# use of lambda in itertools.product for better code

Tags: python, lambda

To help me better understand and write a bit more compact code, I suspect the following can be written in a one liner joining the two `perms =` assignments with the use of lambda. Any python guru?

```
import itertools

l = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e"]]
perms = list(itertools.product(*l))
perms = sorted([",".join(x) for x in perms])
print perms
```

Secondary which I suspect could be done in the same lambda what if `l` is a list of lists of integers as the following completely fails?

```
import itertools

l = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
perms = list(itertools.product(*l))
perms = sorted([",".join(x) for x in perms])
print perms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any lambdas. Just loop directly over the `itertools.product()` generator without converting it to a list first:

```
perms = sorted([",".join(x) for x in itertools.product(*l)])
```

The `[..]` brackets could be omitted, as `sorted()` will convert a generator expression to a list *anyway*, but producing a list object is slightly faster.

Note that your `product()` output is already in sorted order for the specific input you gave, so the `sorted()` is redundant here.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> l = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e"]]
>>> sorted([",".join(x) for x in product(*l)])
['a,c', 'a,d', 'a,e', 'b,c', 'b,d', 'b,e']
>>> [",".join(x) for x in product(*l)]
['a,c', 'a,d', 'a,e', 'b,c', 'b,d', 'b,e']
```

Your second attempt fails because you need to map your integers to strings before you can use `str.join()` on those:

```
l = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
perms = sorted([",".join(map(str, x)) for x in itertools.product(*l)])
```

or better still, convert the inputs to strings *just once*:

```
perms = sorted([",".join(x) for x in itertools.product(*(map(str, li) for li in l))])
```

Comment: Would you not use a generator expression instead, like `sorted(",".join(x) for x in itertools.product(*l))` so there's no intermediate list?

Comment: @KirkStrauser: already directly addressed.  A generator expression will save on memory, but not speed. On my machine, using Python 2.7.10, `sorted([..])` expression takes 2.18 seconds for 1 million repetitions, `sorted(..)` (so only removing the brackets), takes 2.58 seconds for 1 million repetitions.

Comment: Thanks for the super-lightning response. Was actually editing/extending original question as it does not work with numerics... Unsure, whether to remove the extra bit from my question and accept your answer as it addresses the original one, or there is a similar trick for when the lists contain numerics.

Comment: I would leave out the square brackets for prettiness. That said, it is a bit faster to use the list comprehensions, but only just barely; only a few hundred nanoseconds, or about ~5% faster. It comes out to a difference of ~0.3 seconds over a million loops.

Comment: Aaand you beat me to it while I was fiddling with timing :P.

Comment: @Cyphase: Python 2 or 3? In Python 2 list comprehensions don't get a new namespace, making the difference more pronounced.

Comment: @Cyphase: on Python 3, the generator expression can win it again, I got 2.46 for the list comp vs. 2.20 for the generator expression on 3.4.2.

Comment: I tested on Python 2, as that's what the OP is using. On Python 3 they are very close; but both slower than Python 2.

Comment: Of course I'm creating a random list each time, so `randrange` is in play across versions.

Comment: All that said, I would personally use the generator expression until speed became an issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the extended reply.

Answer (score 3):

You can write:

```
import itertools

l = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e"]]
perms = sorted(",".join(x) for x in itertools.product(*l))
print perms
```

This will iterate over the values without unnecessary lists.

Comment: Well, the list is necessary if you want the result faster for reasonable sizes of input. Only for more memory-intensive sizes (where swapping might occur) the generator expression might win out.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. You both answered it the same way... Not even sure which one would be classified as the accepted answer.